# Do meteor showers start slowly each night?

Tags: meteor-shower

Does the frequency of the number of visible meteors during a daily shower start off lower at the beginning only to increase as the night goes on or does the frequency remain the same for the entire night?

Comment: Related: https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/23560/16685

Comment: see answers to [What makes some meteor showers continue for days, while the “Unicorn shower” can be shorter than one hour?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/34018/7982) and also [Meteor shower predicted to be best viewed BEFORE midnight (for reasons other than the moon)?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/23555/7982)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The rate depends on the distribution of the dust and rocks in space as the earth passes through the cloud. Some may be very short lived, some may start slowly, some may tail off slowly, some may last all night - they are all different.

Answer (score 3):

The number you are able to detect increases as it gets darker.

The number occurring is apt to be greater when the zenith of the sky is closest to pointing in the direction the earth takes orbiting the sun 
(like a windshield hitting more bugs than back window when a car is moving forward)

The last factor I can think of at the moment is the density of comet tail material earth happens to be passing through (in its orbit around the sun) 
Which could unfortunately be not when your local the zenith is 'forward in our orbit' and when it is dark.