# Have meteor showers been predicted for planets or solar-system bodies other than Earth? Have attempts been made to detect them?

Tags: solar-system, orbital-mechanics, comets, meteor-shower

Per the linked Q's and A's in [Why do particles from a comet that result in meteor showers spread out mostly along the comet's orbit?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35919/7982) and it's answer, meteor showers happen on Earth when it passes through the orbit of a comet.

There are a lot of known comet orbits in the solar system, and some of them likely intersect the orbits of planets other than Earth.

**Question:** Have meteor showers been predicted for planets or solar-system bodies other than Earth? Has there been any attempt to look for experimental evidence of these meteor showers, perhaps using radio or optical observations from spacecraft near some of these bodies?

Comment: companion question: [What fraction of comet orbits that intersect Earths' orbit result in known meteor showers?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/35922/7982)

Comment: does https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comet_Shoemaker-Levy_9 count?

Comment: @JohnDvorak ya that crossed my mind :-) It may not end up as the *accepted answer* but it would certainly make for a spectacular supplementary answer. I guess you could argue that those became meteors after the breakup and before entry.

Comment: Ooops,  I misread  "detect"  as  " **deflect** "   :-) .  that would be interesting

Comment: [NASA's Cassini spacecraft has provided the first direct evidence of small meteoroids breaking into streams of rubble and crashing into Saturn's rings. 
These observations make Saturn's rings the only location besides Earth, the moon and Jupiter where scientists and amateur astronomers have been able to observe impacts as they occur.](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/cassini/whycassini/cassini20130425.html)

Comment: @KeithMcClary very intriguing link as always, thanks!

Comment: @uhoh Off-topic : [During the Covid-19 lockdown Springer is making 408 expensive scientific books available for free.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3647617/252672). There  does not seem to be a question like this in Astro, Earth or Physics.

Comment: @uhoh [Original link.](https://link.springer.com/search?facet-content-type=%22Book%22&package=mat-covid19_textbooks&%23038;facet-language=%22En%22&%23038;sortOrder=newestFirst&%23038;showAll=true) Also: [A package to download free Springer books during Covid-19 quarantine](https://www.statsandr.com/blog/a-package-to-download-free-springer-books-during-covid-19-quarantine/)

Comment: @KeithMcClary Maybe I can ask one soon, but I have to run out and buy a hard drive ASAP :-) Thanks!

Comment: Links: [here](https://astronomy.com/magazine/ask-astro/2013/07/meteor-showers), [here](https://www.space.com/31186-mercury-may-have-meteor-showers.html). There is also a paper called "annual meteors showers at Venus and Mars" but the link is too long to embed.